# How to determine if a Picker was ended by pressing Cancel or Done?

Tags: codenameone

I'm using the `Pickers` to implement the following behavior: if the user has not previously entered a value, the `Picker` is shown as blank (except an edit button [>]). If the user presses the edit button the `Picker` is set to a reasonable default value (by overriding `Picker.pressed()`), which the user can then keep or change. If the user presses Done, the edited value is kept and stored.

However, I can't figure out how to detect if the user presses Cancel, in which case the underlying value edited by the Picker should be left with same undefined value it had before launching the Picker (e.g. typically a duration of 0 or a `Date(0)`).

Is there a way to detect how the user ended the Picker? If not, any suggestions for how I might implement the behavior I want?

Comment: This is conceptually problematic since cancel doesn't necessarily exist on all platforms and might not be available. We don't support that exactly because of that reason. There's either modified or unmodified. You can add a "reset to default" button next to the picker.

Comment: Thanks Shai. I think I found a way to do it, posted as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do this that works at least for my use case (not sure it it covers all situations). Since pressing Cancel is the same as NOT pressing Done, I detect if Done has been pressed via an actionlistener and the variable inputValidated and if not, return the old value when getDate() (or getDuration(), getValue() etc) is called. If someone else needs this, here's the essence of the code:

```
        private boolean inputValidated; //true if the user explicitely validated the value by pressing Done?

//in the constructor: 
 addActionListener((e) -> {
            inputValidated = true;
        });
    
     @Override
        public void pressed() {
            if (getDate() == null) {
                if (defaultDate != null) { 
                    inputValidated=false;
                    setDate(defaultDate); 
                } 
            }
            super.pressed();
        }
     
     @Override
        public Date getDate() {
            if (inputValidated) {
                return super.getDate();
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        }
```